# TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'test': object is null or undefinedundefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a function that evaluates a string through a set of regular expressions. Those regular expressions are wrapped as their own objects inside of  `charRules`.

If the string is invalid, return false, else return true.

Example valid string: `1234567890123K`

Example invalid string: `!@#$%^&*!!!&H5`

When a user types in their value to the text input, IE8 throws an error in the console,

`TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'test': object is null or undefinedundefined`

IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari work as expected.

The logic is implemented as a directive. Here's the core logic which is attached to scope,

```
                    scope.validate = function(value) {

                        // Letters and special characters not allowed per country.
                        var charRules = {
                            br: {
                                haveLetters: /[a-zA-Z]/,
                                haveSpecials: /[!@$%^&*()_+|~=`\\#{}\[\]:";'<>?,]/,
                                minMaxLength: /^.{12,25}$/
                            },
                            cl: {
                                haveLetters: /[a-jl-zA-JL-Z]/,
                                haveSpecials: /[!@$%^&*()_+|~=`\\#{}\[\]:";'<>?,\/]/,
                                minMaxLength: /^.{12,25}$/
                            },
                            mx: {
                                haveLetters: /[]/,
                                haveSpecials: /[!@$%^&*()_+|~=`\\#{}\[\]:";'<>?,\/.-]/,
                                minMaxLength: /^.{12,25}$/
                            },
                            pr: {
                                haveLetters: /[a-zA-Z]/,
                                haveSpecials: /[!@$%^&*()_+|~=`\\#{}\[\]:";'<>?,\/.]/,
                                minMaxLength: /^.{12,25}$/
                            }
                        };

                        if (charRules[country]) {
                            if (charRules[country].haveLetters.test(value) || charRules[country].haveSpecials.test(value) || !charRules[country].minMaxLength.test(value)) {
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    };
```

The `country` variable is defined globally. The directive which applies to the HTML is `rut="mx"`

It applies to this HTML,

`<input type="text" id="address_rut" rut="mx" class="input-xlarge" ng-switch-when="mx" ng-model="rutnumber.taxIDNumber" ng-show="editing" required>`

Any thoughts on what causes the string value to not be interpreted in IE8 only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet explorer 8 throws:

> Expected ']' in regular expression

when trying to use an empty brackets in a regular expression.

```
    /[]/
```

You should try to be more specific with the characters that you do not want to match in there
Something like that, depending on your needs you might need to add more excluding conditions:

```
/[^\w^\w]/
```

Comment: This solution is sound. Thanks for your suggestion.

Upvote+

Answer (score 0):

In the above if condition, try

```
null!=charRules[country].haveLetters.exec(value) || null!=charRules[country].haveSpecials.exec(value) || (value.length>12 && value.length<25)
```

as javascript test() does not work in some of the older versions of IE.